# Rails controller is treating JSON object as a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a static JSON file and want to iterate over it in an `.html.erb` template like,

```
<% @data.each do |x| %>
    <%= x['method'] %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm running into an error like below.

```
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007ffb11e33de8>
```

Rails seems to be interpreting the JSON as a string.

**Controller**

```
def index
  @data = File.read("#{Rails.root}/data/docs.json")
end
```

**docs.json**

```
[
    {method: "POST", usage: "xyz"},
    {method: "DELETE", usage: "abc"},
    {method: "GET", usage: "mno"}
]
```

This is confusing because in my text editor I can simply iterate over a json object like,

```
data.each {|x| p x}
```

Can anyone explain why this works differently in a Rails app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should parse a Json file, because `File.read` return a string object thats why an error is raised  `undefined method 'each' for #<String:0x007ffb11e33de8>`:

```
def index
  @data = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/data/docs.json"))
end
```

[Also your file is not a valid JSON notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_sample)

It should be:

```
[
    { "method": "POST", "usage": "xyz"},
    {"method": "DELETE", "usage": "abc"},
    {"method": "GET", "usage": "mno"}
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include but I tried that as well and got an `419: unexpected token` error.